# Is the reference of JAVA different from the reference of C and C ++?

Tags: java, c, pointers, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I have been practicing and learning data structures in C and C ++. Nowadays, I have been using JAVA language frequently and have been practicing data structure with JAVA.

Then one question came up. During the exercise of creating a tree, I did a Coding like C and C ++, but Node was not added.

```
private Node<E> root;

public void insert(E item) {

    Node<E> r = root;
    insert(r, item);
}

private void insert(Node<E> node, E item) {

    if (node == null) {

        System.out.println(item);
        Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(null, item, null);
        node = newNode;
        return;
    }

    if (node.item.compareTo(item) == -1)
        insert(node.prev, item);
    else
        insert(node.next, item);
}
```

BinarySearchTree.

Coding is done as above and nothing is generated.

By the way,

```
    private Node<E> root;

public void insert(E item) {

    if (root == null) {

        Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(null, item, null);
        root = newNode;
        return;
    }
    Node<E> r = root;
    insert(r, item);
}

private void insert(Node<E> node, E item) {

    if (node.item.compareTo(item) == -1) {

        if(node.prev == null) {

            Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(null, item, null);
            node.prev = newNode;
        }
        else
            insert(node.prev, item);
    }
    else {

        if(node.next == null) {

            Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(null, item, null);
            node.next = newNode;
        }
        else
            insert(node.next, item);
    }
}
```

Tree was created because of the above coding.

in conclusion,

Is the reference in C or C ++ different from the reference in JAVA? (This is a stupid question, but I'd appreciate it if you could explain the difference between the two above.)

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: C doesn't have references.  Java and C++ are very different languages; assume the answer is yes (references are different in Java and C++).  At least that way you won't be disappointed.  If you're very lucky, you might be pleasantly surprised; however, things seldom work out like that in the real world.

Comment: In the first code, root is never modified but only read. Therefore, the tree is not built. You need some line "root=..." somewhere or nothing will happen. You can not make references to references, but only references to objects. You can't do that in C++ either, anyways. So the question is, what would you expect to happen and how would the "equivalent" but working C++ code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java object parameters in functions are not like references in c, but more like pointers, which are passed by value, in c where the "." operator in java acts like the "->" operator in c.

So if you assign a value to the parameter node, it is like assigning a new address to the pointer node in c where the pointer is passed by value.
But if you change the object itself by changing its parameters via the "." operator, it is like changing its parameters by using the "->" operator in c.